# How can I allow a (sidecar) container to terminate within a Kubernetes deployment without it restarting?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

My deployment consists of:

- an init container
- a long-running service
- a sidecar that needs to configure a related service.

The sidecar's job is done once it configures the separate service. However, it cannot terminate because Kubernetes will just restart it again. It should not be part of the init container because it should not block the service from running.

Since deployments do not allow a `OnFailure` restartPolicy, my current implementation is to let the sidecar go to sleep after it is done with the configuration task.

Is there a way to allow a container to terminate without the deployment restarting it? Alternatively, is there a way for an init container to run alongside the regular containers?

Some details to address XY problems:

- The service does some processing and dumps results into a database.
- The related service provides an API to the values stored in the database.
- The two services are in separate deployments because I anticipate that they would scale separately.

Example:

```
#my-service.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: my-service-init
          image: my-service
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: postgres://postgres:postgres_password@$db_host:5432/database
          args: ['init_script.py']
      containers:
        - name: my-service
          env:
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: postgres://db_role:db_password@$db_host:5432/database
          image: my-service
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args: ['main.py']
        - name: related-service-configure
          env:
          - name: RELATED_API_SERVICE_ADMIN_ENDPOINT
            value: http://related_api_service/api/
          image: my-service
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args: ['manage_related_service.py']
```

```
#related-api-service.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: related-api-service  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: related-api-service
          env:
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: postgres://db_role:db_password@$db_host:5432/database
          image: related-api-image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
```

```py
#manage_related_service.py
import time
import requests
import json


def upgrade_metadata(query_url, metadata_file):
    with open(metadata_file) as fp:
        metadata = json.load(fp)

    print(f"Querying {query_url}...")
    rsp = requests.post(query_url, json=metadata)
    response = rsp.json()
    print(f"Response to request was:\n{response}")
    if response.get('success') != 'True':
        raise ValueError("Metadata upgrade was not successful")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from environs import Env
    env = Env()
    env.read_env()

    RELATED_API_SERVICE_ADMIN_ENDPOINT = env("RELATED_API_SERVICE_ADMIN_ENDPOINT")
    METADATA_FILE = env("METADATA_FILE", "metadata.json")

    upgrade_metadata(RELATED_API_SERVICE_ADMIN_ENDPOINT, METADATA_FILE)

    # Once metadata has been uploaded, sleep forever
    while True:
        time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: Interesting question. Not sure if there is any clean way other than hacking around the livenessProbe by setting it very high value.

Comment: This question would especially benefit from a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since it is very hard to talk in abstract terms; that said, if you have control over the `command:` of the Pod, then `command: ["bash", "-c", "long-running &\nexec the-main-service"]` may be what you're looking for

Comment: Not an answer to the exact question as you want to use a sidecar container but you can also try to see if you can use "Post-start hooks" for your use case.

Comment: I'll see what I can do in terms of the MCVE - is this more about the kubernetes configuration or the underlying services? Incidentally, @mdaniel running multiple processes has the downside that if `long-running` crashes it's not restarted by kubernetes, but that might still be an acceptable tradeoff.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create [Kubernestes Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) instead of Deployments. Then you should terminate sidecar in.  After that specific container will be automatically terminated too.

You can simulate specific sidecar behaviors. There is example script which will help you to do so:

```
containers:
  - name: example
    image: gcr.io/some/image:latest
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args:
      - |
        trap "touch /tmp/pod/main-terminated" EXIT
        /my-batch-job/bin/main --config=/config/my-job-config.yaml
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tmp/pod
        name: tmp-pod
  - name: envoy-container
    image: gcr.io/our-envoy-plus-bash-image:latest
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args:
      - |
        /usr/local/bin/envoy --config-path=/my-batch-job/etc/envoy.json &
        CHILD_PID=$!
        (while true; do if [[ -f "/tmp/pod/main-terminated" ]]; then kill $CHILD_PID; fi; sleep 1; done) &
        wait $CHILD_PID
        if [[ -f "/tmp/pod/main-terminated" ]]; then exit 0; fi
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tmp/pod
        name: tmp-pod
        readOnly: true
volumes:
  - name: tmp-pod
    emptyDir: {}
```

More information you can find here: [sidecar-terminating](https://medium.com/@cotton_ori/how-to-terminate-a-side-car-container-in-kubernetes-job-2468f435ca99), [sidecars-behaviour](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908#issuecomment-308569672).

Comment: @Nan Lin Does it answer your question.
Have you tried to create a Job ?